# Parsing an object from multiple source files

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I receive zip files and they have as content 8 different files, each with it's own metadata inside.

I have to combine these files into 1 object containing certain metadata. The big issue here is that there will not always be 8 files and the metadata i want to retrieve could be in any of these files stored in there own way.

for now i have created a factory method that initiates the correct parser for each file type and the parser returns the object with the metadata it was able to parse.

Now when this is done i have 8 object's i have to merge into 1 result object with the metadata gathered from these results.

so i could have something like this

```
object  Meta1    Meta2    Meta3    Meta4    Meta5
1       A        -        15       RT       -
2       -        -        15       -        HIGH
3       A        -        15       RT       HIGH
4       -        65       -        RT       HIGH
```

This needs to have only 1 object as output:

```
Meta1    Meta2    Meta3    Meta4    Meta5
A        65       15       RT       HIGH
```

Now i'm wondering what would be the best strategy to solve this issue

- Have my parsers accept my Object as parameter, try to map the data and override if present and then return the Object to be passed again in the next Parser
- Parse all the Object and  try to merge them somehow in the end
- Another strategy?

Comment: Is the handler known before the data is loaded? Given file1 and file2, will your code use `load(file1);load(file2)` or `load1(file1);load2(file2);`?

Comment: I receive the files  loaded and have allready determined the required handler to parse them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I describe some similar work I did. Perhaps it will work for you. I had 7 different file formats across 2 different files.

What I must assume is that your meta-data is effectively keys. Otherwise how can one possibly know which records to merge?

- Create a `CommonData` class

  - A single class to hold any record from any file.
  - A property for each possible meta-field from any incoming file
  - **A property to hold the entire record**
  - As you clearly illustrate - Where meta-fields are the same, there is only one. I.E. only 1 "Meta1", "Meta2"
  - Populate only the appropriate meta fields for a given file/record format.
  - **An `enum` identifing the record type** - what file it comes from essentially; or for me, the file format.
  - **Has an `IEqualityComparer`**
- `CommonDataEqualityComparer`

  - Implements `IEqualityComparer`
  - In my solution your "meta data" were my keys that defined equality for each given record type (file).
  - The equality-comparer object is passed into the `CommonData` constructor.
- An `enum` to identify each source file or unique file format.
- The Factory

  - takes the raw record and it's type - `enum` value
  - Factory passes to appropriate parser based on the `enum` value
  - Factory returns new CommonData object, with it's record-type-specific `CommonDataEqualityComparer` implementation.
- `CommonDataCollection`

  - Between the equality-comparer implementations and `RecordType` property we can find, match, etc. records for each file type.